# Do unused composer packages have an impact on performance or security?

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7

My company wants to use phpmailer, I've already implemented mailgun, but they want to use mailgun when they scale, not now. I'm leaving the company next month and I'm the only PHP developer.

Can I use PHPMAILER, now, leave mailgun package there unused and leave a note for the other guy taking my place

> When the system scales and you decide to use mailgun, please comment
>   out this code and use that code instead

So what happens is, now they're using PHPmailer, mailgun package is left unused on the server. When the right time comes, they'll be using mailgun, PHPmailer will be left unused.

Do unused packages impact either the performance or the security of the application? Because composer autoloads them by default as far as I know.

Comment: You can be sure it is a bad practice (the YAGNI principle)

Comment: That is a good question. its "a bad practice" like @MichałSkrzypek said. It could have a security threat if not update I would assume ?

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek yes I know that, from a programming point of view, but I just want to make the life of the guy coming next a bit easier, because I'm pretty sure they'll need mailgun, the server can't handle the mails volume, they know it too, but they don't want to pay for it yet

Comment: I know you are trying to be a good guy for the company you work for @Lynob, but what if comes and says "no way, I'm not going to use it"? Keep the code simple. If he is a programmer, he will know ho to do it himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It entirely depends on the packages you are using. However:

1. If a package is not used, your application should not load it. The *impact on performance* is maybe neglegible, but at least it will be there.
2. An unused package also does not belong to your production server, it is an unecessary load and if the package is badly written and/or not updated it *may also be a threat to security*.

Steps to do:

1. Out-comment the unused package in your composer.json
2. Leave a note (e.g. in the readme.txt of your application) for the next programmer such that he knows what this is about
3. Run composer update and the package will be removed (at least temporarily)

Comment: How do you out-comment JSON?

Comment: Ah thats complicated, right. If it does not work just drop a note or make a composer.json.WITHMAILGUN as a backup for your follower. 

But documentation/knowledge vs. code should be maybe seperated anyhow. Maybe your company uses confluence or something similar?

Comment: The unused library should not be loaded until it is used, nevertheless.